# Is there a way to pass a method's return value that does not execute the entire method when referenced?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng

In the below code you will see that the beforetest method is returning the `string srnumber`. This variable is a unique identifier that is generated during the execution of the beforetest method. What I want to do is store that unique number and reference it in other methods. 
The issue I am running into is when I do something like

```
public void ReferenceMethod(){
String InvoiceReference = beforetest() 
Searchfield.sendkeys(InvoiceReference)
}
```

the whole `beforetest method` runs which I do not want for various reasons, the main one being it creates a **new** unique number.

```
package fcstestingsuite.fsnrgn;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import pageobjectfactory.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.AjaxElementLocatorFactory;


public class E2ESRInvoiceTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    Ourfsnlogin LoginPage;
    SRCreate SRCreatePage;
    InvoicingPOF Invoicing;
    HomePagePOF HomePage;
    HomePagePOFSC HomePageSC;
    Utilities UtilClass;


    @BeforeSuite
    public String beforeTest() throws InterruptedException {
        SRCreate.webdrive();
        InvoicingPOF.webdrive();
        HomePagePOFSC.webdrive();
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(Utilities.driver, 60), this);
        Utilities.driver.get("fsndevweb:81");
        SRCreatePage = PageFactory.initElements(Utilities.driver, SRCreate.class);
        LoginPage = PageFactory.initElements(Utilities.driver, Ourfsnlogin.class);
        Invoicing = PageFactory.initElements(Utilities.driver, InvoicingPOF.class);
        HomePage = PageFactory.initElements(Utilities.driver, HomePagePOF.class);
        HomePageSC = PageFactory.initElements(Utilities.driver, HomePagePOFSC.class);

        LoginPage.sendUserName("ebluth");
        LoginPage.sendPassword("password");
        LoginPage.clicksubmit();
        LoginPage.USclick();
        SRCreatePage.NavigateToSRCreatebtn();
        SRCreatePage.SRCreationTestHVAC();
        String srnumber = SRCreatePage.SRNumber.getText();
        LoginPage.Logout();
        LoginPage.sendUserNameSP("4335701");
        LoginPage.sendPassword("password");
        LoginPage.clicksubmit();
        LoginPage.SPSRSearch(srnumber);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Invoicing.ActivtityCompletition();
        HomePage.HomePageNaviate();
        LoginPage.SPSRSearch(srnumber);
        return srnumber;
    }
```

I understand that this is the expected behavior when you reference a methods return object. Is there a way to alter that ?  I really don't want to have to include the beforetest code in every method that needs the SR number. Any help is appreciated ! I am also fairly new to java so if I have any mortal sins in my code I apologize in advance lol.

Comment: What do you mean, "I really don't want to have to include the beforetest code in every method that needs the SR number"?  Call `beforeTest()` exactly once, and store the result.  You may need to pass `InvoiceReference` to other methods down the line, if you don't want to call it again.  That's how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about storing the value in a field, and returning the previously computed value on every subsequent call?

```
public class E2ESRInvoiceTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    Ourfsnlogin LoginPage;
    SRCreate SRCreatePage;
    InvoicingPOF Invoicing;
    HomePagePOF HomePage;
    HomePagePOFSC HomePageSC;
    Utilities UtilClass;

    private String cachedSrnumber;

    @BeforeSuite
    public String beforeTest() throws InterruptedException {
        if(cachedSrnumber != null)
            return cachedSrnumber;

        // Your beforeTest() code

        cachedSrnumber = srnumber;
        return srnumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly ! Thank you ! If you don't mind explaining what's the relevance of the if return block ? What would happen if I didn't include that ?

Comment: @Lamar Sure: When the `beforeTest` method is entered for the first time, `cachedSrnumber` is `null`, because it hasn't been set, so the `if` is not entered, the value is computed and then stored in `cachedSrnumber`. When the method is entered a second time, `cachedSrnumber` contains the previously computed value. Therefore, the `if` block is entered and the stored value `return`'ed directly, omitting a second computation. Sorry for the late answer, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Java gives you the possibility to instantiate instance variable which are available class-wide instead of local variables which only appear inside a method or so.

Just do something like this:

```
public class E2ESRInvoiceTest {
     private String invoiceReference;

     public void beforeTest() throws InterruptedException {
         // code
         String srnumber = SRCreatePage.SRNumber.getText();
        // code

        // Here you set your invoiceReference's value only once
        invoiceReference = srnumber;
    }

    // If needed, you can make it reachable for other classes
    public String getInvoiceReference(){
        return invoiceReference;
    }
}
```

And then you can act like this:

```
public void ReferenceMethod(){

    Searchfield.sendkeys(invoiceReference);
}

private void anotherMethod(){
    fooClass.createInvoice(invoiceReference);
}
```

All you have to do is to call your beforeTest() methode at first then.